# Why do we need run time class information in MFC?

Tags: mfc

Why do we need run time class information in MFC? What is use of DECLARE_DYNAMIC and IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC?

Comment: Google "DECLARE_DYNAMIC", "IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC" and "RTTI".

Comment: Tried but was not very clear why we need these macros. Why we need the concept of runtime class information. And how its useful. Can anyone explain with a quick example

Comment: This all explained in the MSDN (see [DECLARE_DYNAMIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ywz9k63y.aspx), [IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/es8sbsx5.aspx), and [Using CObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ybbhxe3.aspx), specifically the section on [Dynamic Object Creation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4a790bwx.aspx)). @MichaelWalz: MFC's dynamic class information is more than RTTI. It also implements class factories, that enable document templates, and serve as the base for object serialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It was the way RTTI was implemented in the very early times of the MFC and C++.
2. This mechanism is used to have a specific "type" (a pointer to a CRuntimeClass) and to create instances of it. I.e. the Document/Frame/View model is using such runtime classes in the document templates. (specially DECLARE/IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC).
3. Also the dynamic serialization stuff of CArchive is using this runtime class objects.